# Is ISA deviation always zero at the stratosphere?

Tags: weather

I watched a video of a pilot who stated that the ISA deviation is always near zero when at the stratosphere, is this true? And if so, what is the science behind it?

Here is the video

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ISA Model**

In the International Standard Atmosphere (ISA) model, the temperature at sea level is set at 15°C and decreases at a lapse rate of 2°C per 1,000 feet. This lapse rate is maintained up to [Flight Level](https://skybrary.aero/articles/altitude-flight-level-and-height) (FL) 360, where the temperature stabilises at -57°C. Beyond FL360, up to approximately 65,000 feet or 20 km, the temperature remains constant at -57°C in the ISA model (see Note 1).

**Stratosphere Meteorology**

The stratosphere exhibits a relatively stable temperature profile, particularly in the lower levels. This is fundamentally different from the troposphere. In the troposphere, temperature generally decreases with altitude due to the adiabatic expansion of rising air. In contrast, the stratosphere's temperature remains relatively constant, largely owing to the presence of the ozone layer. This layer absorbs ultraviolet (UV) radiation from the Sun, releasing heat in the process. This heat offsets the cooling effects of radiation emitted back into space, resulting in a balanced temperature profile.

**The Rule of Thumb**

Given that the ISA temperature at FL360 and above is -57°C, and the stratosphere also maintains a constant temperature of approximately -57°C, the ISA deviation would indeed be zero. This holds true whether you're at FL370, FL400, or even higher altitudes. Hence, the rule of thumb mentioned in the video—that a zero ISA deviation likely indicates you're in the stratosphere—is generally accurate.

**Limitations**

However, there are limitations to this. For instance, if you experience a consistent ISA deviation of zero throughout your climb, it becomes challenging to discern when you've transitioned into the lower stratosphere's constant temperature zone. Additionally, the lower stratosphere temperature close to the tropopause can vary ([see Stratosphere Temperature Forecasts)](https://www.netweather.tv/charts-and-data/stratosphere) due to factors like solar cycles, volcanic activity, and latitude. This rule of thumb may be less reliable outside the latitudes above 65° N/S - due to both a lower tropopause and typically colder stratosphere temperatures.

This rule of thumb will break down when the actual tropopause is lower then FL360 as the following example illustrates.

Scenario: Flying at high latitudes in the winter, the tropopause is at FL290.

The ISA model suggests a temperature of -43°C at this level. If the actual temperature is -57°C, your ISA deviation would be -14°C. The negative deviation indicates you're still in the colder troposphere, when in fact you might well be in the stratosphere.

---

*Note 1: The lapse rate stopping at FL360 in the ISA Model is commonly referenced in aviation meteorology textbooks and across the web (for example: https://skybrary.aero/articles/international-standard-atmosphere-isa). Many places, like Wikipedia, reference ICAO Doc 7488 Manual of Manual of the ICAO Standard Atmosphere for this, however this document doesn’t actually state this fact. I have been unable to provide a source for this but is generally accepted.*

Comment: Adding to some of the confusion is that technically the flat temperature lapse exists only in the tropopause, which is the boundary between the troposphere and the stratosphere. In the stratosphere the temperature actually rises at a rate of 0.3 °C per 1,000 feet. However for general purposes the tropopause is considered the lower level of the stratosphere, and since the stratosphere's temperature lapse above the tropopause of +0.3 °C is relatively small compared to the troposphere's -1.98 °C per 1,000 feet, the stratosphere is often described as one layer having a flat temperature lapse.

Comment: I couldn't find an ISA source but the [U.S. Standard Atmosphere 1976](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19770009539/downloads/19770009539.pdf) table 4 on page 3 shows from 0-36K feet (0-11 km) a lapse rate of -1.98 °C/1000ft (-6.5 K/km), from 36K-65K feet a lapse rate of 0, and from 65K-105K feet a lapse rate of +0.3 °C/1000ft. Interestingly the word tropopause does not appear anywhere in the document, however the table seems to indicate that the USSA model  tropopause begins at 36K feet, stratosphere at 65K, upper stratosphere at 105K feet, stratopause at 154K feet, mesosphere at 167K feet.